# SimpleITK Reader error in a python multiprocessing context

Tags: python, io, python-multiprocessing, reader, simpleitk

so I have an error when trying to use simpleITK to read multiple files in multiprocess context in python to speed up a normal pipeline.

Excepected Behavior:
The pipeline works as before paralellization with no issues.

Actual Behavior: The pipeline fails at the last couple of dicoms read with the excecption

**When doing this with the same multiprocessing code but on 1 core there are no errors**. The error appears when doing multiprocessing and usually at the last elements that need to be read with this exception `Exception thrown in SimpleITK ImageFileReader_Execute: bad allocation`

The Multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing
from workers import batch_function

mp_list = split_input_list(number_of_splits=int(no_of_cpus), input_list= local_test_json_data)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
results = pool.map(workers.batch_function, mp_list)
```

In this batch_function I call the simpleItk reader and other business logic.

The IO:

```
    reader = sitk.ImageFileReader()
    reader.SetImageIO("GDCMImageIO")
    reader.SetFileName(dcm_path)
    dcm = reader.Execute()
```

Where dcm_path is an absolute path

After this I just run a function over the dcm that works as expected.

The error is raised for `reader.Execute()`

Full exception:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File " \lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File " \lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "  auto_workers.py", line 60, in batch_autodetection
    raise e
  File "  auto_workers.py", line 57, in batch_autodetection
    dcm = reader.Execute()
  File " \lib\site-packages\SimpleITK\SimpleITK.py", line 5779, in Execute
    return _SimpleITK.ImageFileReader_Execute(self)
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ImageFileReader_Execute: bad allocation

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "  mp_Script.py", line 89, in <module>
    run_batch_autosegmentation()
  File "  mp_script.py", line 57, in run_batch_function
    results = pool.map(auto_workers.batch_function, mp_list)
  File " \lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File " \lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ImageFileReader_Execute: bad allocation

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I don't think the GDCM reader is completely thread safe.  Or maybe you're running out of memory?  I suggest reporting an issue. Can you create a minimum example, say reading 1 Dicom 100 times concurrently?  And describe your system: OS, Python version, SimpleITK version, memory, etc.  https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK/issues

Comment: As you pointed out I am running out of memory. That is why this works single threaded.